# Hamcrest assertion on two values

Tags: java, hamcrest

I can easily do an assertion with two possible results:

```
assertThat(result, anyOf(true, false)); // just a sample, doesn't make sense as an assertion
```

However, I need to perform assertion that one of my results is equal to some value:

```
assertThat(result1 || result2, is(true));
```

The above works, but error message doesn't say which result was `false`. Is there anything similar to the below in Hamcrest?

```
assertThat(anyOf(result1, result2), is(true)); // just a hypothetical assertion
```

Comment: What's the problem with assertTrue(result1 || result2). If the assertion fails then both result1 and result2 are false. You don't need anything special to deduce that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write the assertion in reverse:

```
assertThat(true, anyOf(is(result1), is(result2)))
```

This will still throw an assertion error when either `result1` or `result2` isn't `true`, and the message will tell both final values or `result1` and `result2`... in the expected part, which makes it a bit awkward.

---

From your question:

> However, I need to perform assertion that one of my results is equal to some value:

This means that your real use-case is determining whether the list of your results has a given value. This can be clearly expressed with:

```
assertThat(Arrays.asList(result1, result2), hasItem(true));
```

This is asserting that the list formed by the two results has the given item. If it doesn't, the assertion error will be:

```
Expected: a collection containing <true>
     but: was <false>, was <false>
```

The message tells you the value of each element in the collection.